# Modal Dialog Box using JQuery & AJAX

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I've been trying to add a modal dialog box in my page, which is displayed on the click over a hyperlink, and fetches content from another URL.
Problem is, I couldn't find a way to make it modal, as it is still possible to interact with the background page, and I don't want that.

Here's the code I am using,

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a class="ajax" href="login.html">Open as dialog</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.loading {
  background: url(/img/spinner.gif) center no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var ajaxDialog = $('<div id="ajax-dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
  ajaxDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  $('a.ajax').live('click', function() {
    ajaxDialog.load(this.href);
    ajaxDialog.dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Please, if anyone can help to make it modal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ajaxDialog.dialog("modal","true");  ?

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I'm a beginner in jQuery.